# Why is this getJSON call returning undefined?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON service running on an internal server that returns the following record:

```
    {
    "getLTCWithIDsResult": {
        "AIMSubmissionID": "",
        "BrokerName": "",
        "DateApplied": "/Date(1389302726241-0600)/",
        "Dirty": false,
        "EffectiveDate": "/Date(1389302726241-0600)/",
        "ExpiringPremium": 0,
        "GrandTotal": 0,
        "Insured": {
            "Address1": "",
            "Address2": "",
            "City": "",
            "County": "",
            "InsuredName": "Nice Try Bro",
            "MailAddress1": "",
            "MailAddress2": "",
            "MailCity": "",
            "MailCounty": "",
            "MailState": "",
            "MailZip": "",
            "Phone1": "",
            "Phone2": "",
            "State": "",
            "Zip": ""
        },
        "IsRenewal": false,
        "Locations": [ ],
        "PercentChange": 0,
        "PolicyID": "",
        "QuoteID": 0,
        "QuoteVersion": 0,
        "RetroDate": null,
        "Status": null
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get a piece of this record onto an HTML page using the following script.  Unfortunately, the data variable  in the success: function(data) line is continually returning "undefined".  Can anyone be of some assistance?

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var appViewModel 
    // AppViewModel
    function AppViewModel()
    {
        this.InsuredName = ko.observable();
    }
    var appViewModel = new AppViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(appViewModel);

    $.getJSON("http://waltweb01:85/LTCEPLWS/LTCJSON.svc/getLTCWithIDs/'4'",
    {
        success: function (data)
        {
            incomingData = data;
            appViewModel.InsuredName(incomingData.InsuredName);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is your JavaScript code also running on `http://waltweb01:85`?  If not, then you'll need to configure either JSONP or CORS.

Comment: `incomingData.InsuredName` is the wrong way to access the property you are looking for.

Comment: No, the JS is running on my dev box. And will be running (hopefully) under another domain.  I suppose I'll Google up JSONP/CORS.

Comment: Plugging in the CORS piece into my web.config has solved the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's *not* how you use `$.getJSON`.  You only use `success: function()` when using `$.ajax`.  When using the shorthand methods (`$.getJSON`, `$.post` and `$.get`), you just pass the function, *not* an object.

```
$.getJSON("http://waltweb01:85/LTCEPLWS/LTCJSON.svc/getLTCWithIDs/'4'", function(data){
    incomingData = data;
    appViewModel.InsuredName(incomingData.InsuredName);
});
```

Comment: If you want to get technical, that's not how you use `getJSON` either. With the implementation of the promise interface, it is suggested you migrate your code to use `done`, `fail`, and `always`.

Comment: @JustinNiessner: I guess, but this is still fine.

Comment: Actually, it's not. The `success` callback is deprecated (which is what your suggestion relies on) and could be removed at any point in a future release.

Comment: @JustinNiessner it's not suggested or required, it's an alternative. There's nothing wrong with not using the promise interface.

Comment: @JustinNiessner No, it is NOT deprecated, and it is not being removed. you mis-interpreted the deprecation notice, it's talking about something entirely different.

Comment: @JustinNiessner: I'm assuming you're referring to `An alternative construct to the success callback option, the .done() method replaces the deprecated jqXHR.success() method. Refer to deferred.done() for implementation details.`.  It's saying that doing `$.getJSON().success()` is deprecated.  That was a method used before jQuery's promises were introduced.  Doing what I've shown is still 100% ok :)

Comment: Proper usage troll strikes again. :-) Sometimes I can't help myself.

Comment: Thanks Rocket! This plus your CORS suggestion above has solved this issue.